# Separable field extension with bounded simple extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I’d like to get some help about an exercise in Field theory (J. Bastida, ‘Field extensions and Galois theory’, p. 157, problem 2).

*Let K be a field and let L be a separable extension of K. Suppose that there exists a positive integer n such that [K(α):K] is less of equal than n for every α in L. Prove that L is finite over K and [L:K] is less of equal than n.*

[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677029/field-extensions-of-finite-degree-and-primitive-elements) proves it in characteristic 0, but I’d like a proof independent of the characteristic. There they say the result is proved in Lang’s ‘Undergraduate Algebra’, but I haven’t found it yet.
A hint (found in Bosch, ‘Algebra’) is to apply the primitive element theorem (which he states as: every finite separable extension is simple) to the subfields of L containing K and of finite degree over it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem like the answer in the question you linked ever uses the assumption that the fields have characteristic $0$. That proof should work just as well for characteristic $p$.